# cv::solve with DECOMP_SVD using C++ has different results from Python and Java(Kotlin)

Tags: python, c++, opencv, svd

I found an interesting issue with different results of SVD (Singular Value Decomposition) in my project.
I need to find intersections by lines (4 points).
I have 2 vertical lines and 2 horizontal lines.

I wrote the following code for **Python**, and it works correctly:

```py
a = numpy.array([
    [0.99773484, -0.06726905],
    [0.02908471, 0.9995769]
])
b = numpy.array([
    [180.0],
    [264.66666]
])
_, (x0, y0) = cv2.solve(a, b, flags=cv2.DECOMP_SVD)
# x0 = 197.87232204
# y0 = 259.02119276
```

Also I wrote the same code using **Kotlin**, and it works correctly, too:

```kotlin
val a = Mat.zeros(2, 2, CvType.CV_32F)
a.put(0, 0, 0.99773484)
a.put(0, 1, -0.06726905)
a.put(1, 0, 0.02908471)
a.put(1, 1, 0.9995769)
val b = Mat.zeros(2, 1, CvType.CV_32F)
b.put(0, 0, 180.0)
b.put(1, 0, 264.66666)
val linearFit = Mat()
Core.solve(a, b, linearFit, Core.DECOMP_SVD)
val x0 = linearFit.get(0, 0)[0]
val y0 = linearFit.get(1, 0)[0]
// x0 = 197.87232971191406
// y0 = 259.02117919921875
```

But when I wrote this code using **C++**, I got different results:

```c
cv::Mat a = cv::Mat::zeros(2, 2, CV_32F);
a.at<float>(0, 0) = 0.99773484;
a.at<float>(0, 1) = -0.06726905;
a.at<float>(1, 0) = 0.02908471;
a.at<float>(1, 1) = 0.9995769;
cv::Mat b = cv::Mat::zeros(2, 1, CV_32F);
b.at<float>(0, 0) = 180.0;
b.at<float>(1, 0) = 264.66666;
cv::Mat linearFit;
cv::solve(a, b, linearFit, cv::DECOMP_SVD);
double x0 = linearFit.at<cv::Vec3b>(0, 0)[0];
double y0 = linearFit.at<cv::Vec3b>(1, 0)[0];
// x0 = 81.000000
// y0 = 182.000000
```

Is this a problem with my syntax or with opencv2.framework for iOS?
I tested on opencv2.framework v.3.4.19 and v.4.1.0.

P.S. The function to find intersections I got in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46572063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type issue.

`Vec3b` means three values of `uint8_t`.

`cv::solve()` likely returned `float` (`CV_32F`) values. It might have returned `CV_32FC1`, i.e. single-channel, or `CV_32FC3`, i.e. three-channel.

You might have to use `Vec3f`, if the resulting Mat is 3-channel. If not, `float` would be correct.

If it's not a 32-bit float, different types might be required. `CV_64F` is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT helped me.
Correct syntax is:

```c
double x0 = linearFit.at<float>(0, 0);
double y0 = linearFit.at<float>(1, 0);
```