# Corner detection with Hughlines transformation

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I need to detect corner of a paper on given image. It will always be a cropped part of whole picture containing only one of the corners. My idea was to transform image by bluring and Canny edge detection to get outlines and then aplying Houghlines to get coordinates of corner.

However i get some problem to actualy detect anything consistently and precisly by Hough lines and I'm running out of ideas what can be the cause here.

I've tried  tresholding instead of Canny, but it's not gonna work due to many variations in applicable images. I've downcaled whole image to make it easier to see just edges of paper, but still no improvement. Increasing line tresholds make lines from paper content diapear, but at the same time edge lines disapear from time to time

Input
[image: Input]

Edges
[image: Edge detection]

Results
[image: Results]

Code to reproduce

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('inv_0001-01.1_0_corner.jpg')

resized = cv2.resize(img, (250,250), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel_size = 5
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel_size, kernel_size),0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur_gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

cv2.imshow('edges', edges)

cv2.waitKey()

min_line_length = 50  
max_line_gap = 20 

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1,  np.pi / 180, 5, np.array([]), min_line_length, max_line_gap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(resized,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),5)

cv2.imshow('hough', resized)

cv2.waitKey()
```

My go-to result would be coordinate of paper corner in given image, but in this post I'm rather looking for some help in understanding how to use Houglines for such tasks

Answer (score 7):

This answer explains how to find the corner. Finding the corner requires a two part solution. First, the image needs to be segmented in to two regions: paper and background. Second, you can look for corners in the segmented image.

[image: iamge2]

After you find the edges, floodfill the image to segment the paper from the background (this is the floodfill image):

```
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
# Floodfill from point (0, 0)
cv2.floodFill(edges, mask, (0,0), 123);
```

Now that you have segmented the image, get rid of the text on the paper using a mask (this is the image titled 'Masking'):

```
bg = np.zeros_like(edges)
bg[edges == 123] = 255
```

After you get the mask, appl the canny edge filter again to get the out line of the paper (HoughLines needs an outline not a mask...this is the 'Edges after masking' image):

```
bg = cv2.blur(bg, (3,3))
edges = cv2.Canny(bg,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
```

Now you can run your HoughLines algorithm on the cleaner image. I used a different HoughLines algorithm than you did, but yours should work too. Here is the full code that I used:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Create a multi plot
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,3, sharex=True)
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/IRcCAWL.png')
resized = cv2.resize(img, (250,250), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
# Show source image
axarr[0,0].imshow(resized)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel_size = 5
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel_size, kernel_size),0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur_gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
# Show first edges image
axarr[0,1].imshow(edges)
h, w = edges.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
# Floodfill from point (0, 0)
cv2.floodFill(edges, mask, (0,0), 123);
# Show the flood fill image
axarr[0,2].imshow(edges)
floodfill = edges.copy()
bg = np.zeros_like(edges)
bg[edges == 123] = 255
# Show the masked image
axarr[1,0].imshow(bg)
bg = cv2.blur(bg, (3,3))
edges = cv2.Canny(bg,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
# Show the edges after masking
axarr[1,1].imshow(edges)

min_line_length = 50  
max_line_gap = 20

def intersection(line1, line2):
    """Finds the intersection of two lines given in Hesse normal form.
    Returns closest integer pixel locations.
    See https://stackoverflow.com/a/383527/5087436
    """
    rho1, theta1 = line1[0]
    rho2, theta2 = line2[0]
    A = np.array([
        [np.cos(theta1), np.sin(theta1)],
        [np.cos(theta2), np.sin(theta2)]
    ])
    b = np.array([[rho1], [rho2]])
    x0, y0 = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
    x0, y0 = int(np.round(x0)), int(np.round(y0))
    return [[x0, y0]]

import math
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 100, None, 0, 0)
# Draw the lines
if lines is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        rho = lines[i][0][0]
        theta = lines[i][0][1]
        a = math.cos(theta)
        b = math.sin(theta)
        x0 = a * rho
        y0 = b * rho
        pt1 = (int(x0 + 1000*(-b)), int(y0 + 1000*(a)))
        pt2 = (int(x0 - 1000*(-b)), int(y0 - 1000*(a)))
        cv2.line(resized, pt1, pt2, (123,234,123), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

xy = tuple(intersection(lines[0], lines[1])[0])
resized = cv2.circle(resized, xy, 5, 255, 2)
# Show the image with the corner
axarr[1,2].imshow(resized)
# Add titles
axarr[0,0].set_title('Source Image')
axarr[0,1].set_title('Edges')
axarr[0,2].set_title('Floodfill')
axarr[1,0].set_title('Masking')
axarr[1,1].set_title('Edges after masking')
axarr[1,2].set_title('Hough Lines')
# Clean up
axarr[0,0].axis('off')
axarr[0,1].axis('off')
axarr[1,0].axis('off')
axarr[1,1].axis('off')
axarr[1,2].axis('off')
axarr[0,2].axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hmm, i did not thought about it by flood filling. I'll try that asap. My only concern is to make it roboust enough on more picky backgrounds.

Comment: @KrzysiekPrzekwas If you are having trouble segmenting the background trying applying some morphological transformations (like opening): https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html