# Counting Number of squares in an image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, canny-operator, python

I am trying to count the number of squares in an image but landing with the wrong answer.

I followed this [opencv squares](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/squares.py)

[image: Original image]

My result :

[image: Result]

This is counting 226 squares.

I am getting random answers after each operation.
Is there any efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: What number are you expecting, and what results are you getting? And did you use exactly the example code, or did you modify it in any way?

Comment: I am expecting 51 as answer. But I am getting 138 .

Comment: Maybe you could use a modified version of my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60851897/7155708

Comment: Yes @FlorianEchtler I used the same code.