# Swift detect identity card using OpenCV

Tags: swift, objective-c, opencv, object-detection, contour

I'm trying to detect the square of an identity card using OpenCV.
Already install the framework and make the entire setup but everything about detection which I found using other language's example (pyhton, php...)

Can you help me to detect the square on identity card, please ?

Kind regards.

Comment: Detecting squares (edges) is usually done by hough line transform. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60851897/7155708 for a slightly similar problem.
Which language are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using objective-c  or swift as language

Comment: The entire project is in swift but I read a link from medium and it used objective c ans C++

Comment: Here, I found some samples, and nou I'm trying to implement them into the project https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples