# Challenge : How to get the 4-sided polygon with minimum area

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, ocr

I am trying for the four coordinates in an image so that can apply perspective transform on it.
I require a four-sided polygon which do not crop any content in image and cover the minimum area.
I tried some function like "minAreaRect()" but it gives the minimum area rectangle not the possible minimum area using four-sided polygon.
for your understanding i am providing test image.
[Test image -> bind the content with four sided polygon but no content should be lost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL8z4.jpg)

I am able to draw a rectangle on it using contour & minAreaRect() function but that is not optimal to get the minimum area using four sides. I strongly believe that there will be any possible way so that we can draw a four-sided polygon on it which cover all content present on image with minimum area.

Thanks...

Comment: Maybe you should invert the image and try the Radon transform.

Comment: Or its analogue Radon transform, where instead of rotation - shear.

Comment: That is not working...

Comment: What do you expect for the output? Can you mock up something to explain your issue better? Are you trying to extract a single quadrilaterals about both pieces of text or one for each?

Comment: @fmw42 you can read the below comments and solution to get the better idea about the context.

Answer (score 7):

This is bit tricky because the right side of the content doesn't have an edge line. But can be addressed. Below is the code to achieve the expected result:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def order_points(pts):
    rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype = "float32")
    s = pts.sum(axis = 1)
    rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
    rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]
    diff = np.diff(pts, axis = 1)
    rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
    rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]
    return rect

def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = pts
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))
    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))
    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
        [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))
    return warped

def intersection(line1, line2):
    """Finds the intersection of two lines given in Hesse normal form.
    Returns closest integer pixel locations.
    See https://stackoverflow.com/a/383527/5087436
    """
    rho1, theta1 = line1
    rho2, theta2 = line2
    A = np.array([
        [np.cos(theta1), np.sin(theta1)],
        [np.cos(theta2), np.sin(theta2)]
    ])
    b = np.array([[rho1], [rho2]])
    x0, y0 = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
    x0, y0 = int(np.round(x0)), int(np.round(y0))
    return [[x0, y0]]

def resize(image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    if width is None and height is None:
        return image
    if width is None:
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)
    else:
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))
    resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)
    return resized

def draw_lines(image, lines):
    for line in lines:
        rho, theta = line
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
        cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0,0,255), 2)

image = cv2.imread('testimage4.jpg')
orig = image.copy()
draw = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
sqKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (45, 45)) # Increased kernel size
gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, sqKernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find the right most point of the content by finding contours.
# This is required as the content doesn't have extreme right edge line
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]

origH, origW = gray.shape[:2]
xMIN = origW
yMIN = origH
xwMAX = 0
yhMAX = 0

for c in cnts:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if x > 5 and y > 5 and x + w < origW - 5 and y + h < origH - 5:
        if xMIN > x: xMIN = x
        if yMIN > y: yMIN = y
        if xwMAX < x + w: xwMAX = x + w
        if yhMAX < y + h: yhMAX = y + h

# Edge detection and houghlines transform for finding edge lines    
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 50, 200)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 100)

# Filter out irrelevant lines from houghlines transform
strong_lines = np.zeros([12, 1, 2]) # Increased number of considered strong_lines
n2 = 0
for n1 in range(0,len(lines)):
    for rho,theta in lines[n1]:
        theta_diff = np.abs(np.abs(theta) - np.abs(strong_lines[0, 0, 1])) * 180 / np.pi
        if theta_diff > 90:
            theta_diff -= 90
        if rho < 0:
           rho*=-1
           theta-=np.pi        
        if n1 == 0:            
            strong_lines[n2] = rho, theta
            n2 = n2 + 1
        elif n2 < 12 and not np.isclose(theta_diff, 45, atol=15):
            closeness_rho = np.isclose(rho,strong_lines[0:n2,0,0],atol = max(image.shape) / 10) # One-tenth of the image width/height 
            closeness_theta = np.isclose(theta,strong_lines[0:n2,0,1],atol = np.pi/36)
            closeness = np.all([closeness_rho,closeness_theta],axis=0)
            if not any(closeness):
                strong_lines[n2] = rho, theta
                n2 = n2 + 1

# Removing the blank strong_lines entries
if n2 < strong_lines.shape[0]:
    strong_lines.resize(n2, 1, 2)

# Grouping the filtered lines in horizontal and vertical categories
vert_ind = np.abs(strong_lines[:, :, 1] - 1.5) > 0.5
vert_lines = strong_lines[vert_ind]
hori_lines = strong_lines[np.logical_not(vert_ind), :]

test = np.argsort(np.abs(vert_lines[:, 0]))
vert_lines = vert_lines[test]

test = np.argsort(np.abs(hori_lines[:, 0]))
hori_lines = hori_lines[test]

# Extra vert_line to cater the right side where no houghlines will be detected
# After checking if the right most line is already there
far_point1 = intersection(vert_lines[0], hori_lines[0])
far_point2 = intersection(vert_lines[-1], hori_lines[-1])
if not np.isclose(far_point1[0][0], xwMAX, atol=10) and not np.isclose(far_point2[0][0], xwMAX, atol=10):
    vert_lines = np.append(vert_lines, [[xwMAX, vert_lines[0][1]]], 0)

# Finding the intersection points of the lines
points = []
num_vert_lines = vert_lines.shape[0]
num_hori_lines = hori_lines.shape[0]
for i in range(num_vert_lines):
    for j in range(num_hori_lines):
        point = intersection(vert_lines[i], hori_lines[j])
        points.append(point)

# Drawing the lines and points
draw_lines(draw, vert_lines)
draw_lines(draw, hori_lines)
[cv2.circle(draw, (p[0][0], p[0][1]), 5, 255, 2) for p in points]    

# Finding the four corner points and ordering them
pts = np.asarray(points)
four_vertices = order_points(pts.reshape(pts.shape[0], pts.shape[2]))

# Giving a 5 pixels margin for better readability
four_vertices[0] = four_vertices[0][0] - 5, four_vertices[0][1] - 5
four_vertices[1] = four_vertices[1][0] + 5, four_vertices[1][1] - 5
four_vertices[2] = four_vertices[2][0] + 5, four_vertices[2][1] + 5
four_vertices[3] = four_vertices[3][0] - 5, four_vertices[3][1] + 5 

# Perspective transform to get the warped image
warped = four_point_transform(orig, four_vertices)

# Displaying the results
cv2.imshow("Input", resize(image, height = 650))
cv2.imshow("Marks", resize(draw, height = 650))
cv2.imshow("Warped", resize(warped, height = 650))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The input, marked input and warped output are as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Following changes are made in an attempt to make it generalized:

1. Increased the kernel size of morphological CLOSE operation from (21, 21) to (45, 45). This is for better detection of the text area edges.
2. Increased the number of considered strong_lines from 6 to 12.
3. Generalized the rho closeness tolerance from fixed 100 value to 1/10 of image width or height whichever is larger.
4. Added checking to remove blank strong_lines entries.
5. Added condition to check if there is already right-most edge line detected. If so then no need to add extra vertical orientation line to cover the full content.

This modified code applied for all four test images and each of them produced the warped images correctly. Below are the warped images for each of the test images:

**First warped test image:**

[image]

**Second warped test image:**

[image]

**Third warped test image:**

[image]

**Fourth warped test image:**

[image]

Comment: Please share the other images to see if there is any need for modification of the above code. But as far as this particular question is concerned with your provided test image, this should be the right solution.

Comment: @abc2xyz: Made few changes as outlined in the edited answer. With these changes all the four test images are correctly warped. If these are as you expected please consider to accept the answer.

Comment: But as i have more datasets so this solution is generating error like:                 far_point1 = intersection(vert_lines[0], hori_lines[0])

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: Can you please share the images which are generating errors.

Comment: @abc2xyz: This is a very bad dataset. All the contents are not visible as well. Need to have some quality in the dataset to make it work with generalized solution.

Comment: Thanks @amras, i will check for "how to enhance the quality in image". If you have any idea please share.

Comment: i tried using PIL enhance function to increase the quality of image, even after that solution is not showing any response to that test image.

Comment: Hi @amras, can you please explain your solution as i am unable to understand some part of it. These are like irrelevant line and strong line filtering, blank line, intersection etc.

Comment: @abc2xyz: I suggest you read documentation on HoughLine Transform. ```cv2.HoughLines``` function returns lines ordered in terms of voting. The line with most votes is the strongest line returned. When we iterate through the lines in that order, there will be lines which are very close to each other. We need to keep the first strong line and filter out others. Also there can be lines slanted around 45 degrees which will be filtered out. The blank lines will be produced because of array size declaration at the beginning. These will be removed by resizing ```strong_lines array```.